# Get certain part of a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to get a certain part of a dict. The part I need is in bold and I'm not sure how i can get to this (I need to do this on other keys as well as this is just one key)

{" Complete the following statement: changing state from ---(1)--- to gas is known as ---(2)---.": {"['1: liquid; 2: evaporation', '1: liquid; 2: melting', '1: solid; 2: evaporation', '1: solid; 2: melting']":
**"1: liquid; 2: evaporation"**, "['1: liquid; 2: deposition', '1: liquid; 2: sublimation', '1: solid; 2: deposition', '1: solid; 2: sublimation']": "1: solid; 2: sublimation"},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write the dict out a little bit more clearly, you can see that this is a dict containing a dict, aka a nested dict.

```
{" Complete the following statement: changing state from ---(1)--- to gas is known as ---(2)---.": 
    {
        "['1: liquid; 2: evaporation', '1: liquid; 2: melting', '1: solid; 2: evaporation', '1: solid; 2: melting']": "1: liquid; 2: evaporation",
        "['1: liquid; 2: deposition', '1: liquid; 2: sublimation', '1: solid; 2: deposition', '1: solid; 2: sublimation']": "1: solid; 2: sublimation"
    }
}
```

To access the value you marked in bold, you would first have to access the nested dict within the top-level dict. You can do this via `d['keyname']` or `d.get('keyname')`.

```
d = {
    " Complete the following statement: changing state from ---(1)--- to gas is known as ---(2)---.": {
        "['1: liquid; 2: evaporation', '1: liquid; 2: melting', '1: solid; 2: evaporation', '1: solid; 2: melting']": "1: liquid; 2: evaporation",
        "['1: liquid; 2: deposition', '1: liquid; 2: sublimation', '1: solid; 2: deposition', '1: solid; 2: sublimation']": "1: solid; 2: sublimation"
    }
}

nested_d = d.get(" Complete the following statement: changing state from ---(1)--- to gas is known as ---(2)---.")
print(nested_d.get("['1: liquid; 2: evaporation', '1: liquid; 2: melting', '1: solid; 2: evaporation', '1: solid; 2: melting']"))
# output: "1: liquid; 2: evaporation"
```